# Error in a - b : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: ggplot2

```
Q

    {r}

    cambio2 <- data.frame(cambio)

    cambio2 %>%
      ggplot(aes(y = receita,
                 x = despesa
                          )
    ) + geom_point()
```

Quero fazer o gráfico, porém não aparece os pontos no gráficos e aparece o seguinte erro:

> Error in a - b : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Apresente uma amostra de seus dados para que possamos entender qual o tipo de problema está ocorrendo. Use dput(cambio2)  para obter a amostra e edite o poste com essa saída.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que seja isso que você queria, correto?

```
lines = 'mês ano receita despesa 
1 2018 778.7376 1579.185 
2 2018 611.4827 1362.005 
3 2018 544.0717 1532.969 
4 2018 498.8309 1324.723 
5 2018 428.6952 1496.460'

dados = read.table(textConnection(lines), header = T)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dados %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = receita, x = despesa)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: map]

Comment: Rodei sua sintaxe no RStudio e no R console e o erro se repete.                     Error in a - b : argumento não-numérico para operador binário

Comment: Você está rodando o script como ".R" ou como ".Rmd"? Seria mais fácil você colocar um print da tela para avaliar o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Segue os dados:

mês  ano  receita  despesa
1   1 2018 778.7376 1579.185
2   2 2018 611.4827 1362.005
3   3 2018 544.0717 1532.969
4   4 2018 498.8309 1324.723
5   5 2018 428.6952 1496.460

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Desde já agradeço.